# Trying to make a spinner in a fragment and getting an error could youse a suggestion

Tags: android, spinner

The thing is when i try to set up a simple spinner into the second fragment of my application i get an error which i believe is appering because it has to do something with the main activity but im not sure what.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)

        setupspinner()




    }
}

private fun setupspinner() {

    val adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.zemlje1,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        spinner.adapter = adapter
}
```

}

The this, and the spinner are in the red sorry if i haven`t formated the question as i sould have had.

Comment: Plase be more specific about your problem. What happened exactly? Do you have an error? Can you provide a replicable example? Please consider reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this help take a look here. https://ibb.co/yY1HBh3 https://ibb.co/487bQGB